# Unattended Windows Vista & 7: Show the Internet Explorer Icon on the Desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, unattended

In an unattended installation how do I tell Windows I want the Internet Explorer icon on the Desktop? Can I do this from `unattended.xml`? Or do I need a registry key or command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows Vista & 7, there is no more a desktop Internet Explorer icon like there was in Windows XP, so there is no setting you can use in order to show it on the desktop.

If you really need an Internet Explorer icon on the desktop, you'll have to place a shortcut there; but it will not provide the same functions the XP icon provided (f.e. quick access to Internet Explorer settings).